# Parsing dates from a webpage

Tags: c#, parsing, asp.net

I have two inputs (TextBox) on my front end.

The following code parses them from their string representation to a`DateTime` object.  If it fails, it then sets default values.

```
DateTime dateFrom;
DateTime dateTo;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text, out dateFrom)) { dateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7); }
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtDateTo.Text, out dateTo)) { dateTo = DateTime.Now; }
```

However, the code looks bulky. Is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing this a lot, you could consider a custom method for it:

```
public static DateTime TryParse(object from, Func<DateTime> failureResult)
{
    DateTime result;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(from, out result))
    {
        result = failureResult();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or (for when you're not accessing time-sensitive `DateTime` values (i.e. not `DateTime.Now()`):

```
public static DateTime TryParse(object from, DateTime failureResult)
{
    DateTime result;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(from, out result))
    {
        result = failureResult;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This calls the `failureResult` delegate that will return your `DateTime` if DateTime's TryParse fails.

Your usage would be:

```
DateTime dateFrom = TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text, ()=>DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7));
DateTime dateTo = TryParse(txtDateTo.Text, ()=> DateTime.Now);
```

Or with the second snippet:

```
DateTime dateFrom = TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7));
DateTime dateTo = TryParse(txtDateTo.Text, DateTime.Now);
```

Sadly you cannot make a static extension method so this will have to exist somewhere else (although you could make it an extension of string).

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to change the bulkiness much but there are a few things you can do:

- indent your code. It will take more space but it will also be more readable:

```
DateTime dateFrom;
DateTime dateTo;

if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text, out dateFrom)) 
{ 
    dateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7); 
}
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtDateTo.Text, out dateTo)) 
{ 
    dateTo = DateTime.Now; 
}
```

- Wait for C# 6 which has inline-out-variables. This will make it possible to write the `TryParse` like this:

```
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text, out DateTime dateFrom))
```

or even

```
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text, out var dateFrom))
```

- Use `DateTime.UtcNow`. By using `DateTime.Now` you're dependent on the location of your server which might be a problem some time in the future when you host it elsewhere.
- Consider making a datetime picker available in the frontend instead of a textbox. It's a lot more user-friendly and it will avoid invalid dates.

Answer (score 2):

I like Nick Udell's concept, but I prefer using extension methods in this case and avoiding using negative cases - I find these more confusing at 2 AM, when something is broken, than using the positive case.

```
public static DateTime TryParse(this DateTime defaultValue, string TextToParse) 
{
    DateTime.TryParse(TextToParse, out defaultValue);
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7).TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text); 
DateTime dateTo = DateTime.Now.TryParse(txtDateTo.Text);
```

Comment: Could simply be preference but `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7).TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text);` would make me think I'm trying to get last week to do the parsing of the text, for some reason.

Comment: @NickUdell, I see what you mean. I would probably switch the method name to something like "TryReplaceWith" to give better clarity.